# PHP: How to extract this string

Tags: php, string

Suppose I've got the following string:

`) [6] => Array ( [2014-05-05 00:0] => My actual content`

If I want to only be left with `My actual content` at the end, what is the best way to split the entire string?

Note: the words `My actual content` are and can change. I'm hoping to cut the string based on the second `=>` string as this will be present at all times.

Comment: Why do you want to get results from `print_r`? Just get it straight from the array? This seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Is that really a string, or just part of an array that you're print_r'ing; if a string wtf!

Comment: Yep I'm print_r'ing an array. The thing is - the key here is a date as you can see. Neither the date nor the title is available to me. Long story short I'm sorting an array based on it's key which is a date (need the array sorted by dates). But I don't know what the date is of a given array item, nor do I know the value related to the key. Is there any other way to retreive the value other than print_r'ing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're just looking to find the first value of an array with keys you do not know. This is super simple:

Consider the following array:

```
$array = array(
    '2014-05-22 13:36:00' => 'foo',
    'raboof' => 'eh',
    'qwerty' => 'value',
    '8838277277272' => 'test'
);
```

---

### Method #1:

> Will reset the array pointer to the first element and return it.

Using [`reset`](http://www.php.net/reset):

```
var_dump( reset($array) ); //string(3) "foo"
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/oc5HnaGb)

---

### Method #2:

> Will reset the entire array to use keys of 0, 1, 2, 3...etc. Useful if you need to get more than one value.

Using [`array_values`](http://www.php.net/reset):

```
$array = array_values($array);

var_dump( $array[0] );  //string(3) "foo"
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/dYwvUsSb)

---

### Method #2.5:

> Will reset the entire array to use keys of 0, 1, 2, 3...etc and select the first one into the `$content` variable. Useful if you need to get more than one value into variables straight away.

Using [`list`](http://www.php.net/list) and [`array_values`](http://www.php.net/array_values):

```
list( $content ) = array_values($array);

var_dump( $content ); //string(3) "foo"
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/e3CGHblE)

---

### Method #3:

> Arrays are iteratable, so you could iterate through it but break out immediately after the first value.

Using a [`foreach`](http://www.php.net/foreach) loop but [`break`](http://www.php.net/break) immediatly:

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $content = $value;
    break;
}

var_dump($content); //string(3) "foo"
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/7z14ElEi)

Answer (score 0):

**To Answer your question, on extracting from a string based on last 'needle'...**

Okay, this is quite an arbitrary question, since it seems like you're showing us the results from a `print_r()`, and you could reference the array key to get the result.

However, you mentioned "... at the end", so I'm assuming `My actual content` is actually right at the end of your "String".

In which case there's a very simple solution. You could use: `strrchr` from the PHP manual - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php.

So you're looking at this: `strrchr($string, '=>');`

Hope this answers your question. Advise otherwise if not please.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use foreach loop in a foreach to get the multi dimentional array values.

foreach($value as $key){

```
 foreach($key as $val){

  echo $val;
}
```

}